# How to pass string data to popup or dialog menu

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a name in a TextView. When I click the name "Laura Aikman", I want to pass the mobile number "1111111111111" to the "Call" option on a popup or dialog menu. When I click the name "Sarah Alexander", I want to pass the mobile number "222222222222".

Java code:

```
package com.nasir.dialogmenu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MenuDemoActivity extends Activity {
       TextView Laura_Aikman;
       TextView Sarah_Alexander;
       TextView Anthony_Andrews;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.main);
              final String[] option = new String[] { "Call", "SMS", "Save", "Share" };
              ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, option);
              AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

              builder.setTitle("Select Option");
              builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
              { 
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
              {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub


              }
              });

              final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

              Laura_Aikman = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Laura_Aikman);
              Laura_Aikman.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                           dialog.show();

                     }
              });

              Sarah_Alexander = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sarah_Alexander);
              Sarah_Alexander.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(View v) {
                           dialog.show();
                     }
              });

              Anthony_Andrews = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Anthony_Andrews);
              Anthony_Andrews.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(View v) {
                           dialog.show();
                     }
              });
       }
}
```

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/Laura_Aikman"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
       android:textSize="25sp"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:text="Laura Aikman"/>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/Sarah_Alexander"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
       android:textSize="25sp"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:text="Sarah Alexander"/>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/Anthony_Andrews"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
       android:textSize="25sp"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:text="Anthony Andrews"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So what's your question? You've posted code, what is wrong with it?

Comment: How do you get `1111111111111` from Laura Aikman? It is nowhere in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set mobile number in tag of each view and get number at runtime by calling gettag() method and store at global variable.
On alert option call with saved number like -

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView Laura_Aikman;
    TextView Sarah_Alexander;
    TextView Anthony_Andrews;
    String mobileNumber;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final String[] option = new String[]{"Call", "SMS", "Save", "Share"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, option);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Select Option");
        builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // for making call
                if (which == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "Calling to:" + mobileNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + mobileNumber));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        Laura_Aikman = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Laura_Aikman);
        Laura_Aikman.setTag("11111111111111");
        Laura_Aikman.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mobileNumber = v.getTag().toString();
                dialog.show();

            }
        });

        Sarah_Alexander = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sarah_Alexander);
        Sarah_Alexander.setTag("22222222222");
        Sarah_Alexander.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mobileNumber = v.getTag().toString();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        Anthony_Andrews = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Anthony_Andrews);
        Anthony_Andrews.setTag("333333333333");
        Anthony_Andrews.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mobileNumber = v.getTag().toString();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Do not forget to add permission in manifest file with -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

I think it will help you.

Comment: Thanks it work properly. but if they are use double number such as Mobile and Telephone Number, how to call Telephone number.

Answer (score 0):

- Create separate method for creating dialog. And call that method with after clicking of Name-textview, get mobile number from the source and pass to the method, and in that method use mobile number whrever you want to display and then call dialog.show().

Answer (score 0):

```
   int index = 0;
```

First take one **index integer object**  and store value when user click on particular textbox like below

```
builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
              { 
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
              {
                if (which == 0) {
                  if(index == 1)
                  {
                  // click on Laura_Aikman 
                  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                  intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + 1111111111111));
                  startActivity(intent);
                  }
                  else if(index == 2)
                  {
                  // click on Sarah_Alexander 
                  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                  intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + 222222222222));
                  startActivity(intent);
                  }
                  else if(index == 3)
                  {
                  // click on Anthony_Andrews 
                  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                  intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + 333333333333));
                  startActivity(intent);
                  }
                }
              }
              });

              final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

              Laura_Aikman = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Laura_Aikman);
              Laura_Aikman.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                           index = 1;
                           dialog.show();

                     }
              });

              Sarah_Alexander = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sarah_Alexander);
              Sarah_Alexander.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(View v) {
                           index = 2;
                           dialog.show();
                     }
              });

              Anthony_Andrews = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Anthony_Andrews);
              Anthony_Andrews.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(View v) {
                           index = 3;
                           dialog.show();
                     }
              });
```

Comment: I want to Pass mobile Number to dialog menu on click TextView Name

Comment: For above implementation no need to pass phone number from dialog menu. There is different condition I put in builder adapter onClick event for each textview. so you can easily do Call,SMS, Save and Share.

Comment: Where Can I put Mobile Number & Where Can I use Call Intent

Comment: I want to Use One Dialog Menu
I need, When I click "Laura Aikman" Mobile Number 111111111111111 Set on "Call"
and,
When I Click "Sarah Alexander" Mobile Number 222222222222 Set on "Call" Option.

Comment: Above code should be work which you want.